# is the zsh guide on the zsh official website out-dated?

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to find a zsh guide and I notice [the guide on the official website](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide.html) hasn't been updated for over a decade. So I'd like to know if there are anything in that guide has been changed and should be skipped when reading, and how many new things has been added during these years. Or are there any more recent guides that I can read instead of the official one?

Answer (score 0):

The official guide probably **is** outdated.
I would advise you to use the `man` command. In this case `man zsh` and the consult the following hyper-links:

[Linux Zsh Man Page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zsh)

[The Zsh Wiki](http://zshwiki.org/home/)